# Java volatile necessary with synchronized access?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, volatile

In the following case, is `volatile` redundant? Would removing `volatile` make any difference here? Alternatively, would leaving `volatile` but removing the synchronized block and synchronized modifier make any difference here?

```
private volatile boolean registered;

synchronized boolean registered() {
  return registered;
}

void setRegistered(boolean registered) {
  synchronized (this) {
    this.registered = registered;
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be notable to mention that the `synchronized` statements are *likely unnecessary* (unless you want those methods to not be called during other synchronized blocks elsewhere we dont see). In thise case using `synchronized` to encapsulate a `volatile` variable is defeating the purpose of the `volatile` status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless you have some other access that you have not shown, `registered` is fine without the `volatile`.

Removing `volatile` would speed up the code ever so slightly, I think.  But I think the main benefit to removing `volatile` is it cleans up the code for a maintainer.

In this case, there's no difference between `volatile` and the synchronized methods that I can see, so use one or the other.  (Except that the synchronized methods make the object you are using to guard the `registered` field **public**, which can be good and bad.  A private `volatile` keeps the synchronization lock private.)

---

To try to clarify that last statement, if you have a class like this:

```
public class Reg {
    private boolean registered;

    synchronized boolean registered() {
      return registered;
    }

    void setRegistered(boolean registered) {
      synchronized (this) {
        this.registered = registered;
      }
    }
}
```

Which you then create a new instance of:

```
public class Test {
  public static Reg reg;
  public void static main( String... args ) {
     reg = new Reg();
     synchronized( reg ) {
            // do stuff
     }
  }
}
```

Anyone else trying to access `reg.registered()` while that lock in `Test` is held will block until said lock is released.  The lock is public to anyone who can see the object.  This can be good and bad.  It lets other classes control access to your methods, which can be good for atomicity but it might also bake some thread control into a source-base, where it gets spread all over instead of just encapsulated by one class.  Good and bad.  There's probably other examples of why that can be good and bad, this is just one.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean about making the object public? Are you saying the class of the `this` will become public?

Comment: "unless you have some other access" -- including *internal* access.  If this class touches member variable `registered` only via the accessor and mutator methods presented then synchronizing those protects the variable sufficiently, but if it is also accessed directly via other, unsynchronized instance methods, then not.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Right, if I maybe wanted to do more with this class or "future-proof" it, I might want to prefer `volatile` over the synchronized parts.

Comment: Well, `this` is always public.  If I call `Reg reg = new Reg()` on your object, then `reg` is equal to `this`.  It's always available to anyone who can invoke a ctor on your class, or get an object reference via some factory method.

Comment: @markspace Yeah, I understand that. :)
I just don't understand what you mean by:
"Except that the synchronized methods make the object you are using to guard the registered field public, which can be good and bad. A private volatile keeps the synchronization lock private."

Comment: Well, if you understand it, then you understand what I mean.  You understand that your pointer internally called `this` is the same thing that other classes see when they create that object.

Comment: @markspace, I'm not tracking with you, unless you're saying the same thing I did in my earlier comment.

Comment: @markspace Oh, I see. So, it might be better to think of the volatile as synchronizing on the `registered` rather than on the `reg` object. Right?

Comment: Sure, and I think that's what it actually does, although `volatile` never actually holds a lock.